# Get Min and Max of Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query will give me the list of IDs I need to perform an update immediately after running this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 WorkflowEventProcessingID
FROM Master.WorkflowEventProcessing
WHERE ProcessingToken IS NULL
ORDER BY WorkflowEventProcessingId
```

[image]

Is there a way to get the min (55034) and max (55038) IDs of this range, in one select statement, so I can do something like this:

```
UPDATE WorkflowEventProcessing
SET ProcessingToken = <guid here>
WHERE WorkflowEventProcessingId >= @minId
  AND  WorkflowEventProcessingId <= @maxId
```

I tried something like this, but I'm way off:

```
DECLARE @minId INT
DECLARE @maxId INT

SELECT TOP 5 @minId = min(WorkflowEventProcessingID), @maxId = MAX(WorkflowEventProcessingID)
FROM Master.WorkflowEventProcessing
WHERE ProcessingToken IS NULL
ORDER BY WorkflowEventProcessingId
```

**EDIT**

I don't want to do an UPDATE with a sub-SELECT because I'm getting a deadlock on this. So I was told to separate the SELECT and UPDATE to give a separate DELETE process a chance to run between the UPDATE and SELECT.

Comment: Regarding the edit and deadlock.  Did you try and put with (nolock) on you sub select?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT`/`INTO` to a temporary table to buffer the id's you want to process?  Or create a table variable and use `INSERT`/`SELECT` to achieve the same end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
DECLARE @min INT
DECLARE @max INT

select @min = min(WorkflowEventProcessingID), 
       @max = max(WorkflowEventProcessingID)
from (
        SELECT TOP 5 WorkflowEventProcessingID
        FROM Master.WorkflowEventProcessing
        WHERE ProcessingToken IS NULL
        ORDER BY WorkflowEventProcessingId
     ) x
```

And then

```
UPDATE WorkflowEventProcessing
SET ProcessingToken = <guid here>
WHERE WorkflowEventProcessingId between @min and @max
```

Comment: That looks like what I want, but it doesn't parse when I tried it: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Okay, it worked for me when I added that x. I don't think that was in there when I first copied the code. What does that x represent?

Comment: You need to specify an alias name for every sub query. I called it `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a subquery instead of a range:

```
UPDATE  WorkflowEventProcessing
SET     ProcessingToken = <guid here>
WHERE   WorkflowEventProcessingId in
        (
        SELECT  TOP 5 WorkflowEventProcessingID
        FROM    Master.WorkflowEventProcessing with (updlock, holdlock)
        WHERE   ProcessingToken IS NULL
        ORDER BY 
                WorkflowEventProcessingId
        )
```

Comment: This is actually what I originally had, but I can't do a select in the where clause. See my edit. Sorry, should have had that there in the first place...

Comment: A deadlock can usually be avoided with the `updlock` hint

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do it like this?:

```
UPDATE WorkflowEventProcessing
SET ProcessingToken = <guid here>
WHERE WorkflowEventProcessingId IN (SELECT TOP 5 WorkflowEventProcessingID
FROM Master.WorkflowEventProcessing
WHERE ProcessingToken IS NULL
ORDER BY WorkflowEventProcessingId)
```

Ok, seeing your comment that you can't use a `SELECT` on the `UPDATE` (though I don't really get why you can't), and assuming SQL Server 2005+, you can try the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5 WorkflowEventProcessingID
    FROM Master.WorkflowEventProcessing
    WHERE ProcessingToken IS NULL
    ORDER BY WorkflowEventProcessingId
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET ProcessingToken = <guid here>
```

Comment: @BobHorn - I updated my answer to address your new restriction, see if it helps

Comment: So are those two separate SQL calls? Would that give a DELETE process a chance to run in between them?

Comment: So here's the problem... I don't know enough to know if this is better than juergen's answer. This answer is nice, but the goal is that I need something that won't deadlock with a delete process that is also running.

Comment: @BobHorn - I don't think that it should give you any problems, but sadly I'n not 100 percent certain either, sorry